# How to instruct Spotless to ignore a code segment?

Tags: format, spotless

How can I instruct the [Spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless) code formatter to ignore a specific code section?

I wrote this Java code section:

```
String content = Joiner.on(System.lineSeparator()).join(
    "services:", 
    "- name: name", 
    "  image: artifacts-dev/image"
);
```

Spotless formats it to this:

```
String content =
        Joiner.on(System.lineSeparator())
            .join("services:", "- name: name", "  image: artifacts-dev/image");
```

I want to instruct Spotless to ignore (skip formatting) the above code segment.

How do I do that?

---

For comparison, the [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) formatter can be instructed to [ignore code segments](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript) by adding a comment:

```
// prettier-ignore
```

Is there a similar feature for Spotless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotless can be turned off and on using the [toggle comments](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle#spotlessoff-and-spotlesson), `spotless:off` and `spotless:on`. So the above code block could look like below:

```java
// spotless:off
String content = Joiner.on(System.lineSeparator()).join(
    "services:", 
    "- name: name", 
    "  image: artifacts-dev/image"
);
// spotless:on
```

For the `spotless:off` and `spotless:on` comments to take effect, the toggle needs to be enabled explicitly in the language-specific or custom config blocks. A minimal gradle config, with the toggle enabled for java is below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.18.0'
}

spotless {
    java {
        eclipse()
        toggleOffOn()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following when using Spotless with Maven.

Step 1: Add the following in your mvn plugin under spotless

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
     ...spotless config
    <configuration>
      <java>
        <toggleOffOn />
      ...
      </java>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Step 2:

Add the following in your Java Code:

```
// spotless:off
   public void someMethod() {
     String str = "temp";
       str = "I want this unformatted";
    ....
   }
// spotless:on
```